# understand loop for pages and link

Tags: python, get, python-requests

from lxml import html
import requests
import json

page = requests.get('https://libertyvf.tv/series/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

serieLinks = tree.xpath("//div[@class='divstreaming']/a/@href")
print('serieLinks', serieLinks)

page = requests.get(serieLinks[0])
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

episodeLinks = tree.xpath("//a[@class='num_episode']/@href")
print('episodeLinks', episodeLinks)

page = requests.get(episodeLinks[0])
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

## how create a loop for pages please

## TODO: Select Uqload VF and/or VOSTFR

streamingIdVf = tree.xpath("//div[@heberger='uqload' and @title='Regarder sur uqload en VF']/@streaming")
print('streamingIdVf', streamingIdVf)

page = requests.get("https://libertyvf.tv/v2/video.php?id=" +  streamingIdVf[0] + "&type=series")
print('page', page.text)

parsed_json = (json.loads(page.text))
print('parsed_json', parsed_json)

embed = parsed_json['bande']

print('embed', embed)

## I want all link embed of the all page , how create a loop please